# Controlling the caching of the detail data in a master/detail relationship

Tags: delphi, master-detail, delphi-xe5, dbexpress, tdbgrid

I have a sample app downloadable [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35370420/TestDbGrid.rar). The app contains two TClientDataSet objects, a master and a detail. The relationship is defined through the field id (master) feeding the parameter :id (detail) (it is link of type master field to detail parameter). It uses dbexpress and it needs to be run against an MS SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012 (by default it connects to localhost/master) and it doesn't read any data, it only runs some queries that generate artificial records. The detail query implements a 1 second delay for testing purposes.

Based on my observations of this app, it seems that, as I navigate through the master records the detail records are cached. If I navigate to row 5, then go to row 1, then come back to row 5 the details for row 5 are not refreshed (as proved by the dt field).

My question: is it possible, using this pattern (i.e. master/detail TClientDataSet objects), to control the caching of the detail records? To be more specific, is there a way to always refresh the detail data upon navigating back to the same row?

Thanks